# Dynamic Rendering of UI Elements in PCL Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question,is it possible to render labels or buttons or any UI element on the form dynamicaly?
for Eg: 
I am building a Mobile app which is replicate of my website, so the pages and fields will be same the UI will be different.
if on the website i add a new field in a form, so can i add that field directly to my Mobile Form without coding anything?

So Basically i want to store it in the Database, and when loading the page fetch the values and render the UI.

Is this Possible with Xamarin forms?

Comment: Yes.  There is nothing to prevent you from dynamically creating a layout and populating it with elements.

Comment: @Jason Do you have an example on how to achieve it? or can you guide me in right direction to achieve it?

Comment: Also can i convert the XML of the website page into a page of Xamarin forms?

Comment: Conceivably, yes.  It really depends on how your layout is defined.

Comment: Any Example that you have? @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();

// controls is an IEnumerable of control types
foreach(var s in controls) {

  switch (s.ControlType) {
    case "Label":
      sl.Add(new Label() { Text = s.Caption });
      break;
    case "Textbox":
      sl.Add(new Entry());
      break;
    case "Button":
      sl.Add(new Button() { Text = s.Caption });
      break;
    // add additional cases for whatever types of controls you want to support
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. You can store Xamarin Forms XAML in the database, and render that XAML dynamically without writing code. The answer above will work, but it's not an elegant solution because you will need to write code.

If you clone this repo, there is a sample for rendering XAML dynamically:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

You can store the XAML in the database and use this method to load the UI.